# Google Maps Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the drop down autocomplete working.

It seems like I should be able to start tying now and the textbox will begin to autcomplete. Right now nothings happening.

```
var autocompleteOptions = {
componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
};

var startInput = $('#start')

var autocompleteStart = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(startInput, autocompleteOptions);
```

HTML

```
<input class="input-box form-control" type="text" id="start" value="Current Location">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an actual DOM node not a jQuery object to the Autocomplete.
Try this:

```
var node = startInput.get(0);
var autocompleteStart = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(node, autocompleteOptions);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. My problems ran deeper and I was calling autocomplete before the map was initialized